# I am getting corrupt files after parsing through them

Tags: python, matlab, parsing, io, special-characters

I have many output files from a molecular dynamics code (Lammps) and I have a script that parses through the files and calculates a bunch of parameters from the output files. Each file  is between 4 -17MB and the script parses through 768 of these files in around 3 minutes. The format of the files are text and not binaries.

Here is the problem:

The script stops after processing 4 to 5 of these folders (4~5*768) complaining about a reshape error problem. But the real  reason is that there are a bunch of "special characters" are inserted inside the text without any good reason. I am certain that this file has not been  corrupt before the script parsed through it and the only reason these characters are inserted inside the text is actually running the script.

The script is written in python and I use the 'r' key in command below to make sure that the script does not have write access to the file.

```
fid = open(file_path, 'r')
```

I re-wrote the same script in Matlab and the same problem exists there too making me believe that it is a I/O issue related to my hardware rather than a coding issue.

I run this script on an ubuntu workstation with ext4 format hard drives and 64 GB of ram.
Interestingly when I run the same script on a cluster I am not able to replicate this problem. Even the parallel version of this script runs perfectly fine on the cluster without a problem but not on my local machine.

Here is the part of the script which does all the reading with the opened file the rest of the file does the calculations. In the end I write the results in a separate file which is a very small file (50 KB).

```
        for file_name in list_files:
            if 'dump' in file_name:
                print file_name
                gb_name = dir_list[j]
                gb_num = int(file_name[file_name.find('.')+1:len(file_name)])
                i += 1
                file_path = read_path + '/' + file_name
                fid = open(file_path, 'r', 1)
                junk = fid.readline(); junk = fid.readline(); junk = fid.readline();
                num_lines = int(fid.readline())
                junk = fid.readline()
                if len(junk) > 26:
                    x_lims = map(float, fid.readline().split())
                    y_lims = map(float, fid.readline().split())
                    z_lims = map(float, fid.readline().split())
                    a_tri = abs(x_lims[1] - (x_lims[0]-y_lims[2]))
                    c_tri = abs(z_lims[1] - z_lims[0])
                    gb_area = a_tri * c_tri
                    junk = fid.readline()
                else:
                    x_lims = map(float, fid.readline().split())
                    y_lims = map(float, fid.readline().split())
                    z_lims = map(float, fid.readline().split())
                    gb_area = abs(x_lims[1] - x_lims[0]) * abs(z_lims[1] - z_lims[0])
                junk = fid.readline()
                tmp = fid.readlines()
                fid.close()
                if len(tmp) == num_lines:
                    coords = np.array(map(float, ''.join(tmp).split())).reshape(num_lines, 7)
                    coords[::, 0:2].astype(int)
                else:
                    raise Exception('Number of lines is not consistent with number of data points.')
```

---

Here is an example of the corrupt file. Note the special characters:

```
99463 2 51.5597 211.814 41.7614k4.26088e-13 -3.35999 
99881 2 52.1696 212.526 39.0575 4.91923e-/ef3 -3.35998
```

Please leave a comment here if you have had similar experiences.

Comment: Can you please post a section of the corrupt file and the code you are using? It's hard to debug if we can't see exactly what you are doing.

Comment: What special characters? Are you talking about `e-13`?

Comment: No. I am talking about the extra k and /ef that my text interpreter has added to represent the special characters. These characters change the pattern of the file and cause error in the script.

Comment: Ok so first the file is fine in a text editor, and you run the Python script. Afterwards you open in a text editor again and the file has changed? Can you also sure `md5sum filename` before and after to see if the file checksum is the same?

Comment: Please note that this problem happens after the script goes through around 3000 files with the same format. I cannot predict when this issue happens. I will try to get the output of md5sum before and after each file is read.

Comment: Looks like clearing up the cache memories alleviates the problem. However problem still exists, just happens less frequently especially when I run the code in parallel.
The command that I use to clear the cache is:


     `sudo sync; sudo echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches`


I need to repeat the above command incrementally to defer the crashing to a manageable time. I wonder writing the code in a non-interpretive language such as C++ or Fortran will solve the problem or it is purely a hardware limitations.